# What makes a name of a generic type parameter, generic?

Tags: java, generics

I am writing a java manual for myself and I like to put solid facts in.
I cant seem to describe the generic type parameter. Am wondering what name appears as generic type to a compiler and not an existing object. I know the convention is letter 'T' and other single letters. But I saw in oracle.docs.com an example like:

```
class name<T1, T2, ..., Tn>{}
```

So now I am confused. For the compiler to take a name as a generic type parameter, must there only be no existing class with that name?
If I had a class Boby:

```
class Boby{ ... }
```

Then if I create a method and misstype the name of the class to Bob:

```
void Method(Bob parameter){}
```

Would this just compile and parameter gets to be generic type?

Comment: `<T1>` is declaring `T1` as a generic parameter (type variable in Java Language Specification), if `Bob` is not declared as such it will not be interpreted as one (*similar* to variable declaration). Example `<Bob> void method(Bob parameter)`

Comment: Why don't you just test it? For a method to be generic, it must declare that it has at least one generic type. And why don't you respect naming conventions? This should be at the very beginning of your guide, long before generics

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Comment: You could have a look at the JLS (Java Language Specification) which defines generic parameters and how name clashes are handled. Generally, a generic parameter must be declared in `<...>` and IIRC it takes precedence over class names - that's why generic types normally are named `T`, `V`, `T2` etc. - because classes normally have longer and more meaningful names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any name can be a generic type parameter. If you declare a generic type parameter `Bob`, and use that name instead of the intended class name `Boby`, the compiler will recognize it as a generic type parameter.

BTW, if you declare a generic type parameter `Boby`, it will hide the class name `Boby`, so writing `Boby` anywhere within the scope where that generic type parameter is defined (either within an entire class or within a single method) will refer to the generic type parameter, not to the `Boby` class.

```
class Something<Bob> {
    void Method1(Bob parameter){} // refers to the generic type parameter Bob

    void Method2(Boby parameter){} // refers to the Boby class
}

class Something<Boby> {
    void Method(Boby parameter){} // refers to the generic type parameter Boby,
                                  // hiding the Boby class
}

class Something<T> {
    void Method(Bob parameter){} // compilation error - Bob is an undefined symbol
}
```

That said, to make your code more readable, it's a good practice to use a single upper case letter as type parameter names.

Comment: Nice explanation thank you. I got the concept of the parameters wrong. Thought they could be as parameters of non-declared type anywhere lol, that would be a fairytale :D

Answer (score 0):

The type parameter declared on a class shadows any actual class, just like a local class would:

```
interface HasValue {
    int getValue();
}
class Foo {
}

class Bar implements HasValue {
    private int value;

    public Bar(int v) {
        this.value = v;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

class Example<Foo extends HasValue> {
    public static final void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Example<Bar> e = new Example<>();
        e.method(new Bar(42));
    }

    public void method(Foo x) {
        System.out.println("x.getValue() is " + x.getValue());
    }
}
```

That works just fine, because within `Example`, `Foo` is a type parameter, not the class `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

For the compiler to know if a class is used as a generic you need to specify it like so:

```
public class MyClass<T> {}
```

For example if you create a generic for a list, let's assume the following:

```
List<Bob> bobyes = new ArrayList<Bob>();
```

So now you have a list of generics, containing elements of Bob type class.
All the type of each element inside the list is Bob.

If you iterate thru it you will have:

```
foreach (Bob bob : bobyes)
   if (bob instanceof Bob)
      true; -- in this case always true;
```